# Residual Subscript in Time Series

Tags: time-series, arima, notation

I am familiar with the following notation for a simple AR1 model:

$ x_t = x_{t-1} + \epsilon_t $.

However, I recently came across a very well known paper in my area of research, in which the authors provide the following notation:

$ x_{t+1} = x_t + \epsilon_t$.

My initial thought was, that in this case, the $\epsilon$ should have the subscript $t+1$, thus being consistent with the logic implicitly given in the first formula, i.e. period of residual = period of dependent variable.

Aren't the two formulas provided inconsistent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two expressions are equivalent. To see that, suppose we let $a_t = \epsilon_{t-1}$. Then the second model can be rewritten as
$$x_{t+1} = x_t + a_{t+1}$$
or equivalently as
$$x_t = x_{t-1} + a_t.$$

For the observation at time t, the residual from the first model is given by $\epsilon_t$ while the residual from the second model is given by $a_t = \epsilon_{t-1}$.

Comment: Okay, I understand that. However, shouldn't the subscript of the residual be equivalent to the subscript of the dependent variable? I.e. if I "predict" $x_t$, the residual denotes the deviation from the prediction $x_t$ and the real $x_t$ in time $t$ and not $t-1$ (in the AR1 model). In the case you describe, i.e. the case in which the two expressions are equivalent, this is not the case. In your case, the residual subscript is equivalent to the subscript of the independent variable. This does not make sense to me.

Comment: It is easier to understand if the data and residual share the same subscript, but there is no mathematical reason why they should.

Comment: I see, this clears it up for me then. Thanks.

Comment: @ Rob Hyndman; You apply a kind of change of variables rule, and we can generalize that with $a_{t+k}=\epsilon_t$. It can work in pure sum of series, even if I do not see as it can help us and It seems me that bring only confusion. However It seems me that it not work at all in autoregression; in it imply inconsistency. I’m not convinced from the justification “It is easier to understand if the data and residual share the same subscript, but there is no mathematical reason why they should”. It seems me that a good reason exist, even if it is more statistical than mathematical.

Comment: The subscript is not for arbitrary decision, we can't joke with them, them say us something about the time (or “location”) of all variable in the specific problem. This seems me true for any data analysis. In some sense observations can be considered “free” variables but residuals surely is not; them come from calculus on observations. In this case observations are $(x_t,x_{t-1})$ for $t=1,…,T$, and $x_t$ is the regressand, so residual must have subscript “t”. Then $x_t = x_{t-1} + \epsilon_{t-1}$ is not an autoregression.

Answer (score 2):

In general math sense an equation like

$ x_{t+1} = x_t + \epsilon_t$

holds, you can build a time series consistent with it (simple sum of series).
However $\epsilon_t$ cannot be interpreted as residual.

If in the equation $ x_t = x_{t-1} + \epsilon_t $

represent and AR(1) model and, then, the term  $\epsilon_t $ is a residual, the two equation cannot represent the same series. In this sense are not consistent.